# Copy a range in a workbook and paste it in my current/open workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

I would like to copy some data in a workbook (which will always have the same name: NEW LATEST Loanbook) and copy it in the current workbook I am using. This is the code I have for now:

I have an error at line 3: Workbooks.Open
The file I am trying to open is an xlsm file.

Do you have any idea how I can paste it correctly to the other workbook I am using in the correct sheet ?

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\LATEST NEW Loanbook")
Workbooks.Open("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\LATEST NEW Loanbook").Activate
x.Sheets("Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Select
Selection.Copy
Set y = ThisWorkbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Just add the `.xlsm` extenstion to your `.Open` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st** line of your code: Do not forget to mention the files ending (e.g. .xlsm, .xls or .xlsx). *This might be one reason for the error.*

**2nd** line of your code: Once you have declared your workbook as x, you can refer to it by using its name. *This is no reason for your error, but increases the readability of your code.*

```
x.Activate
```

**3rd & 4th** line of your code: Try to avoid using select. You can write this in one lane instead. *This is no reason for your error, but increases the reliability  of your code.*

```
x.Sheets("Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Copy
```

**5th** line of your code. You want y to be ThisWorkbook. As you've currently activated sheet x , this will set y also to your spreadsheet NEW LATEST Loanbook, even though you most likely want to refer to the workbook that you have open at the beginning of the macro. Consider writing this line before opening the other workbook to avoid errors. *This most likely caused your error.*

**6th & 7th** line of your code. See comment of the 2nd and the 5th line. As you want to call the sheet you opened first (not the latest one) and you already declared it as "y", you can refer to it as y.

```
y.Activate
y.Sheets("RAW Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Thus, your total code should like like that one below. Please check if it works.

```
Sub xxx()

Set y = ThisWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\LATEST NEW Loanbook.xlsm") 

x.Activate
x.Sheets("Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Copy

y.Activate
y.Sheets("RAW Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, following on from my comment. When opening an Excel file, it's mandatory to specify to the file type i.e. the file extension, in your case `.xlsm`.

Second, when working with multiple workbooks, it's good practice to set clear workbook objects so it's easy for you to distinguish between them.

Third, in your operation there is no need for you to use copy and paste. Traditionally, in VBA, you use the `.Copy` method as a last resort. In your case you can simply set the ranges to each other.

See below code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Set_Range()
    
    Dim wbNEW As Workbook
    Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
    Dim sFilePath As String, sFileName As String
    
    sFilePath = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\"
    'always include the file extension
    sFileName = "LATEST NEW Loanbook.xlsm"
    
    'two clear names
    Set wbNEW = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath & sFileName)
    Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook
    
    'set values
    wbCurrent.Sheets("RAW Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Value = wbNEW.Sheets("Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks great, but I still have an error coming from mt file path like it was not recognizing the file name. I checked and it's the exact nomenclature. Have you ever encounter this kind of issue based on the name of the file?

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct? You can always copy the path directly from the windows explorer navigation box at the top of the window. That is what I usually do when working with these. I say that because I see by the `-` there is unbalanced space..

Answer (score 0):

You should add the file extension and you don't actually need to select anything or activate any workbook or worksheets. Try this adjusted code and see it works.

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\LATEST NEW Loanbook.xlsm")
Workbooks.Open ("G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Loanbook\LATEST NEW Loanbook")
x.Sheets("Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").Copy
Set y = ThisWorkbook
If Not ThisWorkbook Is ActiveWorkbook Then ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW Payment Holidays").Range("A1:G55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```